# What kind of sharepoint 2010 templatecan I use?

Tags: site-template

Plan to use sharepoint sites as work areas for engagements. Each engagement will have its own site( just one site per site collection because the site size can be > 2 gb and can have 100s of such sites).

All sites will be created out of a common site template but will have context sensitive web parts to setup data.

I am not sure what kind of site template to start with in trying to build out the final site template. The requirements include some libraries for documents some custom web part pages etc and also security trimmed navigation.
Any suggestions on what site template to start with?

Answer (score 1):

I always start with a Blank template, and then turn on any features that I need as I go. Document Libraries are available by default in Blank templates.

Security trimming is always on (it's built into the API).

Comment: I typically go with blank too so I get only what I need and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the answer. 
About security trimming I noticed that if I used a Team Site template and manually created the site navigation using the Quick launch the security trimming is weird (publishing features not turned on).

If I dont have access to a page I can see the link in the Quick Launch but clicking on it shows me the access denied page. Is this how it works? If yes do I have to have publishing turned on to get the more regular trimming where I dont see a link if I dont have access to the underlying object?

Thanks again

Comment: Hmm. Yes, if you manually create the links and so it, they're just recorded as links. They might not even point to SharePoint content, so yes, they're not security trimmed.

At least, I think that's what I found when I looked this before.

Your problem is more one of manually creating the navigation. Instead, set your libraries to appear on the Quick Launch, and don't use manual links.